# Crystal Report Bound to a Type Dataset Throws error when add column from related table

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports 2008 to design reports and the Crystal Reports 2008 runtime to execute them in a web application.  I have created a simple typed DataSet and that has two tables TestTable1 and TestTable2.  Each has a few columns like Id, Text1, and Text2.  I created a test report which uses this Typed DataSet as it's DataSource.  If I add the columns from just one of the tables TestTable1 or TestTable2 the report is easily executed with this code.

```
        report = new ReportDocument();
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("bin/testreport.rpt"));

        var ds = GetData();

        report.SetDataSource(ds);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The problem is that when I add a column from the other table I get this message.

"Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\testreport {94AF2363-CA61-4944-B63E-C0E6E0391C9A}.rpt: The request could not be submitted for background processing."

If I only have columns from one table it works just fine, but adding any columns from the second table gives this error.

Any ideas?  I tried both with and without relations in the DataSet.  I also tried a untyped DataSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Crystal Reports 2008 SP0.

That is no mistake SP0…that’s right zero.  Go figure.  The tricky part of course is being able to find it.  Here is the [link](https://websmp230.sap-ag.de/sap(bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==)/bc/bsp/spn/bobj_download/main.htm).  Check out my [blog entry](http://blog.randallsutton.net/post/Crystal-Report-Bound-to-a-Type-Dataset-Throws-error-when-add-column-from-related-table.aspx) for more info on what options to select.  (I still can't post using the img tag)